How to nominate a participant different from oneself?
How to nominate a participant different from oneself? I did not find out where this question has been answered.

You don't.
To be nominated for the election, you have to nominate yourself.  This makes a lot of sense for this type of position, where it is unpaid volunteer work.
You want someone who is willing to dedicate their time to moderating.  If someone is nominated by others, they may have no real interest in moderating, and so they likely wouldnt be that helpful in reducing workload on the other moderators.
Even if the user still had to agree to the nomination for it to count, a formal system for nominating others might put pressure on them to accept a position that they dont want.

You cannot nominate other people in a regular Stack Exchange election and this is by design. See How can you nominate someone other than yourself for being a moderator? on Meta Stack Exchange.
See Community Moderator Election Format and Design by Jeff Atwood, co-founder of Stack Overflow:

All nominations are by definition self-nominations. Nominating others is absolutely not supported.

See also What is the reason for insisting on self-nomination?, which was answered by Jeff Atwood:

When we did allow outside nominations, it caused a lot of problems:

users often did not know they were nominated by someone else
users sometimes did not want to be nominated at all
it implies a lot of coordination, more than there actually is, between users

There is, I think, an important difference between nominating yourself and accepting someone else's nomination. While in theory this could work and feels very democratic, in practice it typically does not, and has a small but significant chance of causing confusion and possible hard feelings.
Best to let users nominate themselves so there is no chance of confusion or misunderstanding. I also think people who self-nominate are the most motivated to participate, anyway.

Nominating other persons is something I have only seen in private betas, when "pro tempore moderators" are selected to moderate the site during the public beta phase. Nominees can then choose the accept or reject the nomination. The nomination phase is not followed a proper election; instead, the CMs select moderators from the list of nominees. See, for example Who should our moderators be? on Language Learning SE and Accepting nominations — Who should moderate this site? on Literature SE.
If you want nominations from other people, please contact them and encourage them to nominate themselves.
